# Проблема в запуске бота Telegram на pythonanywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram, pythonanywhere

При запуске telebgram бота вы дает ошибку :

```
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Scheduler started
INFO:aiogram.dispatcher:Start polling
INFO:aiogram.dispatcher:Polling stopped
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aleks22/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 980, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[return-value]  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1064, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1049, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 960, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 500, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 505, in _sock_connect
    sock.connect(address)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aleks22/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/aiohttp.py", line 167, in make_request
    async with session.post(
  File "/home/aleks22/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/aleks22/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 536, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/home/aleks22/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 540, in connect
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1064, in create_connection
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/aleks22/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 901, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/aleks22/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1209, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/home/aleks22/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1178, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/home/aleks22/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 988, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Network is unreachable]
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aleks22/napomnBot/bot.py", line 114, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/aleks22/napomnBot/bot.py", line 109, in main
    await dp.start_polling(bot)
  File "/home/aleks22/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 548, in start_polling
    await asyncio.gather(*done)
  File "/home/aleks22/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 339, in _polling
    user: User = await bot.me()
  File "/home/aleks22/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/bot.py", line 304, in me
    self._me = await self.get_me()
  File "/home/aleks22/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/bot.py", line 1755, in get_me
    return await self(call, request_timeout=request_timeout)
  File "/home/aleks22/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/bot.py", line 432, in __call__
    return await self.session(self, method, timeout=request_timeout)
  File "/home/aleks22/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/base.py", line 257, in __call__
    return cast(TelegramType, await middleware(bot, method))
  File "/home/aleks22/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/aiohttp.py", line 174, in make_request
    raise TelegramNetworkError(method=method, message=f"{type(e).__name__}: {e}")
aiogram.exceptions.TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Net
work is unreachable]
```

Подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: `Network is unreachable`

Comment: и как это исправить